# Should streams using Autodispose stop emitting when scope is in ON_PAUSE or in ON_STOP state?

Tags: autodispose

In autodispose library is it by design that when we have a stream with interval operator and autodispose the stream continues to trigger even when the scope has emitted a pause and stop state?

example

```
Fragment {

   override fun onViewCreated() {
      Flowable.just(1).flatMap{ value -> 
         Flowable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS).map{value}
         .autoDispose(viewLifecycleOwner)
         .subscribe{Timber.d("Value: $value")}
      }
   }
}
```

When we change to the next Activity the interval continues emitting the value even though the scope it self goes to ON_PAUSE state and then to ON_STOP state.

behaviour does not change when using

```
    private val scopeProvider by lazy { AndroidLifecycleScopeProvider.from(viewLifecycleOwner) }
```

and use the autoDispose(scopeProvider) instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The corresponding lifecycle event in your example would be `onDestroyView()`, which is after both `onPause()` and `onStop()`. See this diagram for the lifecycle flow: https://i.stack.imgur.com/maMyK.png.

If you want it to stop in pause or stop states you can either

1 - Move this subscription to `onStart()` (for stop) or `onResume()` (for pause)

2 - Manually set the desired end event

```
Fragment {

   override fun onViewCreated() {
      Flowable.just(1).flatMap{ value -> 
         Flowable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS).map{value}
         .autoDispose(viewLifecycleOwner, untilEvent = Lifecycle.Event.ON_PAUSE) // or ON_STOP
         .subscribe{Timber.d("Value: $value")}
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Ah perfect. Now I understand how this works. 

viewLifecycleOwner + autodispose in onResume will complete the stream and then dispose the subscription (freeing memory) and when the user returns to the view / activity it will subscribe the streams again.